# Remote Blob Storage on "remote" SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: remote-blob-storage

This [article on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628583.aspx) reads:

*RBS can be run on the local server running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. To run RBS on a remote server, you must be running SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.*

Does this mean that I cannot deploy SharePoint in two-tier environment (SharePoint on server1, SQL Server on server2) unless I am using SQL Server Enterprise? **Or** does it mean that the BLOBs cannot be installed on a remote server (such as a SAN) unless I have SQL Server Enterprise.

What I am looking at is a two server installation with SharePoint Foundation 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.  I need to know if I can use the RBS FileStream provider in this scenario where the data is stored on a SAN. What is meant by "on a remote server" in the article above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need SQL Enterprise if your BLOB store location is remote to the SQL Server or put another way, somewhere other than where you are storing your content DBs.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking this is correct, just the wording in the TechNet article is bad, "To run RBS on a remote server..." suggests you're running the FileStream provider (hence the SQL Instance itself) on a server remote from the SharePoint installation.

Comment: The SQL EE requirement also applies to 3rd party RBS providers.

Comment: I can confirm with Rob D'Oria, Trying to enable EMC SourceOne RBS provider on a Content Database with SQL Server 2008 Standard -> Not possible.